# Counting Transaction after initial discounted transaction

Tags: python, loops, transactions, discount

I'm stuck! The goal is to count the number of customer transactions after initially being drawn in by a discount to determine "X% of customers never return when the first visit is discounted"

This was the best I could do:

```
postpurchase = (df_coup['DISC_BI'] == 1 & df_coup['LOGDATE'] > df_coup['LOGDATE1'])
```

I gotta think there's a way to loop this or something.

Data Frame:

[image: data frame]

Answer (score 0):

Try using `sum`:

```
postpurchase = ((df_coup['DISC_BI'] == 1) & (df_coup['LOGDATE'] > df_coup['LOGDATE1'])).sum()
```

Comment: Shoot! Got this error. "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'int' and 'DatetimeArray'" I wouldn't think I need to convert the binomial to a string like a logit function...odd